# unable to recover corrupted 32gb sd card

Tags: windows-10, micro-sd-card, memory-error

while doing format my sd card was suddenly removed after that i tried to connected it splits in to two partitions and unable to format that.
i tried disk part cmd but it unable to delete partition due to there is no listing of volumes 
i also tried easyus partition manager but it also not worked
i also tried minitool partition wizard but it also not worked
while using disk part
it listed there are no volumes.
while delete partition it showing that no volume is selected
how can i recover my sd card plese give me suggeetions

Answer (score 0):

You can try a Linux computer or a smartphone with Android (Linux again), to see if the card is still functional. If yes, you can try to format it to FAT 32 from there to make it work again. If the card is very old, most probably it is gone. If it is new card you may recover it with the above-mentioned way.